# "Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer" on some Sony devices

Tags: android

I've got a lot of error reports from Sony devices with Android 5.0.2 in the past few weeks. It seems that  a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs when inflating `ActionBarContainer`. `ActionBarContainer` is an internal class, never used directly in my code.  The only line of my code in the stack trace is a call to `Activity.setContentView()`. Any ideas? Thanks.

The stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.app/com.my.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3500)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3572)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:371)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
at com.my.app.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=7
at android.content.res.Resources.toPreloadCookie(Resources.java:2447)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2475)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3806)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:492)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:115)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:111)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:107)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(ActionBarContainer.java:57)
... 26 more
```

The list of Build.FINGERPRINT of these devices includes:

- Sony/C6802/C6802:5.0.2/14.5.A.0.270/3305956307:user/release-keys
- Sony/C6833/C6833:5.0.2/14.5.A.0.270/3305956307:user/release-keys
- Sony/C6902/C6902:5.0.2/14.5.A.0.270/3750474323:user/release-keys
- Sony/C6903/C6903:5.0.2/14.5.A.0.270/3750474323:user/release-keys
- Sony/C6943/C6943:5.0.2/14.5.A.0.270/3750474323:user/release-keys
- Sony/D5503/D5503:5.0.2/14.5.A.0.270/3750474323:user/release-keys
- Sony/D5803/D5803:5.0.2/23.1.A.1.28/151083418:user/release-keys
- Sony/D6503/D6503:5.0.2/23.1.A.1.28/151083418:user/release-keys
- Sony/D6603/D6603:5.0.2/23.1.A.1.28/151083418:user/release-keys
- Sony/D6616/D6616:5.0.2/23.1.C.0.385/498118161:user/release-keys
- Sony/D6633/D6633:5.0.2/23.1.1.E.0.1/937646546:user/release-keys
- Sony/D6653/D6653:5.0.2/23.1.A.1.28/151083418:user/release-keys

Comment: Same thing when showing Toast, its happening because of badly implementation of `toPreloadCookie`. Problem exists even in 5.1.